# where clause containing union returns the first query only

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm fetching data from 2 tables according to card number from new_cards table and old_cards table
"I want to display card_code and card_status from theses 2 tables if the card_code contains '8'"

```
(SELECT * 
FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN new_cards
WHERE new_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND new_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND new_cards.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND new_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers
INNER JOIN sold_cards WHERE
sold_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
AND sold_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)
```

but the result is card_coldes from the first table only which is new_cards

Comment: It looks like you want a UNION statement, but it isn't really clear.   Can you show a sample of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: code edited please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is a match for that? Remove the second query and see if any results are returned. If a combined row doesn't match all criteria from all tables it will not appear. That means there will have to be rows where it joins both new_cards and solid cards. You might be looking for a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN

Since you don't mention solid_cards in the new_cards condition or vice versa, it's also going to attempt to join every single row matching the second condition, multiplied by every single row in new_cards. Be careful with OR queries like that, they can be extremely inefficient, especially on large databases.

Comment: I want to display data from 2 tables f card_code like '%8%' but I get more fields as you see in the photo attached.

Comment: yes, because you are joining 2 tables that have the same fields, you probably want to use a UNION instead

Comment: OK now working but when adding order by bills.ID the query returns an error when adding it after the last line of the query

Answer (score 1):

Tip: To avoid any duplication in query result all records for each row shouldn't have different value.

and if it happens then you can use distinct function.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you have a vast swathe of repeated code in your query, which I repeat here laid out more systematically and tagged to indicate repeats:

```
(SELECT * 
   FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers  -- ER1A
  INNER JOIN new_cards
  WHERE new_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'            -- NR1A
    AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`         -- ER2A
    AND new_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`    -- NR2A
    AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`              -- ER3A
    AND new_cards.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`          -- NR3A
    AND new_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)      -- NR4A
UNION
(SELECT *
   FROM bills INNER JOIN cats INNER JOIN suppliers  -- ER1B
  INNER JOIN sold_cards
  WHERE sold_cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'           -- NR1B
    AND bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`         -- ER2B
    AND sold_cards.`Sup_ID`  = suppliers.`Sup_ID`   -- NR2B
    AND cats.`Cat_ID` = bills.`Cat_ID`              -- ER3B
    AND sold_cards.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`         -- NR3B
    AND sold_cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`)     -- NR4B
```

The ERxx tags mean 'exact repeat' and NRxx tags mean 'near repeat'.  I would structure the UNION over the minimum amount of data, and using ON conditions with the joins, like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM bills
 INNER JOIN cats ON bills.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
 INNER JOIN suppliers ON bills.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
 INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT * FROM new_cards
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM sold_cards
       ) AS cards ON cards.`Bill_ID` = bills.`Bill_ID`
 WHERE cards.`Card_Code` LIKE '%8%'
   AND cards.`Sup_ID` = suppliers.`Sup_ID`
   AND cards.`Cat_ID` = cats.`Cat_ID`
```

The last two conditions in the WHERE clause are also joining conditions; it would be possible to move them up into the ON clauses.  However, they should also be redundant — or, if they are not redundant, they are quite likely to be the cause of the trouble you're running into.

An advantage of this reformulation is that you can demonstrate what the UNION sub-query returns by simply executing it.  You might prefer to put the filter on Card_Code into the UNION; that way, you see (presumably) fewer rows of data.  That could be done permanently; you might end up with no WHERE clause in your outermost query.

You should also test your original query by simply running the second half of the UNION on its own, to see what it returns.  If, as you suggest, it returns nothing, then you could debug the second half of the query separately.  For exampe, one question for you: do new cards have valid bill codes?

It's not possible to do any more without (minimal) sample data for the tables — say 3 or 4 rows for each of `new_cards` and `sold_cards` (with one of the rows in each not matching the filter condition on Card_Code), and then the necessary supporting rows in the `bills`, `cats`, and `suppliers` tables (shouldn't be more than 8 rows in any of those).

You should only show the minimum necessary columns in each table, plus at most one extra column.  For example, `bills` has columns `Sup_ID` and `Bill_ID`; you should show those values and perhaps one other ('Bill_Name' or whatever), though the one other isn't really necessary.  It also helps to show the minimal schema identifying primary keys and foreign keys.  You seem to have a very interlinked set of tables.

You should show the output you get from your query and the output you expect, and explain why the two are different in the light of your sample data.